# Assign query result to variable

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have following query `cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(addr) FROM list_table WHERE addr = '192.168.1.1'")` to count the number of times the same address (192.168.1.1) appears on `list_table` table. `addr` is of inet type.

When I assign the query to a variable and print its result I get `None`:

```
res = cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(addr) FROM list_table WHERE addr = '192.168.1.1'")
print res # None
```

What is the proper way to get such thing?

Comment: Have a read through Python's [standard database api](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial).

Answer (score 9):

you can use the following steps for retrieving the data for a relational database using python:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # import the desired package
    import MySQLdb

    # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect(hostaddress,user,password,db_name)

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL query using execute() method.
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(addr) FROM list_table WHERE addr = '192.168.1.1'")

    # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method and store the result in a variable. 
    data = cursor.fetchone()

  #OR use fetchall() method to fetch multiple rows and store the result in a list variable. 
 data = cursor.fetchall()

    print data

    # disconnect from server
    db.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `fetchone()` or `fetchall()` to get the rows from the cursor.

Take a look at the [available `fetch` methods](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html?highlight=fetch#cursor.fetchall).

In your case, something along the lines of:

```
res = cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(addr) FROM list_table WHERE addr = '192.168.1.1'")
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a little bit more explanation.

[`execute()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html?highlight=fetch#cursor.execute) method *prepares and executes a database operation* and, according to the documentation:

> The method **returns None**. If a query was executed, the returned values
>   can be retrieved using fetch*() methods.

`fetchone()` is the most convenient to use since your query returns a single value, a count:

```
print(cur.fetchone())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def ApplyQuery (query ,cursor):
   res = cur.execute(query)
   Return cur.fetchall()
   Sql1= “””SELECT COUNT(addr) FROM list_table WHERE addr = %d"””
   Rows=ApplyQuery(Sql1% 192.168.1.1,cursor)
   For r in rows:
      r1=r[0][0] #will give you first column in in first row and so on
```

Comment: Make sure the code is formatted properly. Are you sure the Indentation 
 is right? https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp

Comment: I think need to be fixed(the indentation)